# How to setup Jetty Server in a Dropwizard project?

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard, embedded-jetty

Recently I've started developing with Java, and was introduced to the Dropwizard framework. But what's got me stumped here, is that I'm not getting any resources online which would explain how to set it up a Jetty server with my Dropwizard application (I previously made use of Apache Tomcat, but was told that Jetty is a much better alternative). Also, what is use of Embedded-jetty in it?

(I realize that the nature of the question is rather amateurish, but I couldn't come across any online resource that would explain this succinctly :( ...)

Comment: Which part of `set it up` are not clear ? you need a ressource and register it on the main `environment.jersey().register(resource);`

Comment: If you're new to Java, there a lot to take in before you start copy-pasting code from the internet. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The application part:

```
import io.dropwizard.Application;
public class App extends Application<AppConfiguration> { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new App().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(AppConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
        final AppResource resource = new AppResource();
        environment.jersey().register(resource);
    }
```

The resource with a dummy API to get version:

```
public class AppResource {
    @GET
    @UnitOfWork(readOnly = true)    
    @Path("/version")
    @ApiOperation(
    value = "Retrieve the version") 
    @Timed
    public Version getVersion() {   


 return new Version();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Orel, thanks for your response. Can you guide me to a link, that would show me setup of Jetty server step-by-step with a Dropwizard project?

Comment: There is nothing else to do, jetty is embedded, you can look http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.6/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi Orel, so will simply typing in this type of command in the command prompt -> java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar , be sufficient to kick-start the jetty server?

Comment: Yes , you will have a server listening, default port is 8080

Comment: Hi Orel, in my case the SNAPSHOT.jar file is missing from the project structure. What can I do to create it? In it's absence is there any other way to get Jetty server started? (I'm new to Dropwizard and Java as a whole :( ....)

Comment: Heu, you need to read a maven tutorial or something like this. Try `mvn clean install`